# Maximo - error in configDB

Tags: config, startup, maximo

My maximo server does not startup. The SystemOut.log says to run configDB.

After running `configdb.bat` I get a whole bunch of following errors:
BMXAA6423W - The value for MAXPROP ** could not be cached. No value for the property was found.

[screenshot attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IE32u.png)

Can anyone please help me how to address this problem?
Thanks

Comment: That screenshot is missing much more of the output (copying and pasting it into a text dump somewhere might be more helpful). What I can see in the screenshot looks more like warnings, but aren't actual problems (if I recall correctly, it's been a while). There might be a problem further down in the output though.

Comment: Bah. Nevermind. I see you have been opening new questions as you get more information instead of updating (or closing?) the old ones. The real question is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48290552/maximo-field-length-of-table-not-matching